# Pandas: Read random sample of data using read_json

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, chunks, bz2

I would like to read in a random sample of a large .bz2 file.

Similarly to how you would read in a sample of csv like this:

```
import pandas
import random

n = 1000000 #number of records in file
s = 10000 #desired sample size
filename = "data.csv"
skip = sorted(random.sample(xrange(n),n-s))
df = pandas.read_csv(filename, skiprows=skip)
```

I've figured out how to read the file in chunks, but this isnt random.

```
import os, json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import random
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

temp = pd.DataFrame()

path_to_json = '/content/drive/My Drive/Loghost/' 

json_pattern = os.path.join(path_to_json,'*.bz2')
file_list = glob.glob(json_pattern)

for file in file_list:
    chunks = pd.read_json(file, lines=True, chunksize=3000000)
    i = 0
    chunk_list = []
    for chunk in chunks:
      i+=1
      user = chunk[random.sample(chunk.UserName)] # i want to take a random sample of 100 users
      chunk_list.append(user)
      print("Progress:", i)
      del chunk
      df = pd.concat(chunk_list, sort = True)
    temp = temp.append(df, sort = True)
```

the above-commented line is where I attempt to randomise rows by selecting random samples of the users but it doesnt seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you elaborate on _doesnt seem to work_